# How to insert or update inlog time in new table when user logged in

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to write a query which if the user is valid it stores the time in another table. I have the first part, to see if the log in credentials are valid. But the second part I don't know: get the `id` of the logged in email, then use this `id` to write it to the second table and insert or update the time in this table.

This is my first part of the query/ stored procedure

```
Create Procedure spAuthenticateUser
@Email nvarchar(100),
@Wachtwoord nvarchar(100)
as
Begin
 Declare @Count int

 Select @Count = COUNT(Email) from Signin
 where [Email] = @Email and [Wachtwoord] = @Wachtwoord

 if(@Count = 1)
 Begin
  Select 1 as ReturnCode
 End
 Else
 Begin
  Select -1 as ReturnCode
 End
End
```

This does already work. I tried to add

```
if(@Count = 1)
     Begin
      Select 1 as ReturnCode
      INSERT INTO Logintijd (Id, Tijd)
      Select Id from Signin where [Email] = @Email
     End
```

These are the table I tried to use

```
Create table Signin
(
    Id int identity primary key not null,
    Naam nvarchar(50) not null,
    Email nvarchar(50) unique not null,
    Wachtwoord nvarchar(50) not null
)
```

and

```
Create table Logintijd

(
    Id int not null primary key,
    Tijd smalldatetime not null
)
```

***Tried to do it with the updated class***

```
  IF EXISTS (Select Tijd from Logintijd Inner join Signin ON Logintijd.Id = Signin.Id)
  update Logintijd set Tijd = GETDATE() From Logintijd Inner join Signin ON Logintijd.Id = Signin.Id
  ELSE
 INSERT INTO Logintijd (Id, Tijd)
      Select Id, GETDATE() from Signin where [Email] = @Email
```

This does do update and insert but it does it for all the item in the class

I know I have to do something with **smalldatetime** and the **Getdate()** function

Hope this is clear enough; if not please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need this:

```
if(@Count = 1)
     Begin
      Select 1 as ReturnCode
      INSERT INTO Logintijd (Id, Tijd)
      Select Id, GETDATE() from Signin where [Email] = @Email
     End
```

Comment: Ohh wauw didn't think it would be that easy. Thanks alot did not think GETDATE() could be used like that

Comment: But does this update the time when user logs out and logs later time back in again

Comment: This is an INSERT, so no, it doesn't perform an UPDATE, but you can use GETDATE() in an UPDATE in the same way.

Comment: I tried to figure out how it works the update class but I cannot find what the problem I post the thing that I tried in the original post hope you would still reply

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you want the update to do.   Do you maybe want to use `@Email` in the WHERE clause?